# How can I determine the projection onto $X-Z$ plane of the solid bounded below by paraboloid $z=x^2 +y^2$ and above by the plane $2x + z =3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

How can I determine the projection of the solid onto $X-Z$ plane bounded below by paraboloid $z=x^2 +y^2$ and above by the plane $2x + z =3$

Since the projection is onto $X-Z$, we to have a projection curve equation that will not have $y$. But the plane $2x + z =3$ has no $y$ in it. So how can I get the projection onto $X-Z$ plane? Also, what is the geometric meaning when only one variable {x or y or z} is missing in the equation of a plane ?

Comment: It means that the plane is parallel to the axis that corresponds to the missing variable. Imagine the plane $z=1$, for example, which is parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane. Since $y$ doesn’t appear in the equation $2x+z=0$, it can have any value whatsoever, and this plane is parallel to the $y$-axis.

Comment: Fortunately, the $x$-$z$ plane passes through the axis of symmetry of the paraboloid and is orthogonal to the other plane, so you can find the projection via simple intersection.

Comment: so how do I take the intersection then? because there is no $y$ present. Normally I would've taken value of y from one equation and put it in the other to get rid of $y$. How can I go about doing that in this case ?

Comment: If you’re having trouble getting your head around the missing $y$, try writing the equation of the plane as $2x+0y+z=3$ instead.

Comment: I get that but how do I find the projection ?

Comment: The equation of the $x$-$z$ plane is $y=0$, so set $y$ to zero.

Comment: But if I were to find the projection onto $x-y$ plane, I would not set $z=0$ in the equations. Why is it different here?

Comment: See my second comment.

Comment: @amd thank you but I am sure I won't be able to understand the curves graphically in every question.. so I am looking for a general method to work only with the given equations.. a general method to get projection in any desired coordinate plane

Comment: Projecting onto an arbitrary plane is a relatively difficult problem. In general, you will have to find the locus of intersections of lines that are tangent to the surface of the solid and perpendicular to the plane onto which you’re projecting. A big part of developing one’s mathematical skills is learning to identify symmetries and other features that simplify problems.